# Parameters across different controller in webflow -Grails

Tags: grails

I am looking at a way to access parameter passed from different Url to use in my web Flow. I am getting URl like
----/newUserRegistration/userRegistration?execution=e20s1&tkn=f9e1cfe077c75ec79f39c61543407cac96ae57e2eca6576e5312b2a266cd8df0. New user registration is my controller name and userregistration is flow name. I have to capture tkn parameter and use this for my flow. How do I do this ? Please suggest me on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your Webflow DSL is correct in an action block you can access it with `params.tkn`.

Comment: thanks for the reply... got it.....params.tkn works,but after researching i found params?.tkn is better because it eliminates the possibility of null